# "Не()резко" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"Фотоаппарат снимает хорошо только на ярком солнце, в тени же все выходит не()резко" - слитно или раздельно пишется "не"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите сказать, что выходит расплывчато? Тогда слитно.(Резко - нерезко. Приставка НЕ придает противоположное значение). Вы хотите сказать, что не резко. а расплывчато?  тогда раздельно. (НЕ- отрицательная частица). И к степени нерезкости это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Хорошо, сминаю про "уровни нерезкости", оставляю про оттенки смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, можно и так и так, это будут разные оттенки смысла (разные "уровни нерезкости")